# Submenu disappears over hero unit

Tags: html, css

I have one submenu in use on inner pages, like this page:

http://www.accessnewdawn.com/meet-jo-ann

When you hover over "Areas of Practice", the submenu doesn't appear until you scroll down past the hero unit.

The original theme developer mentioned writing a JS script that would change the following values to "0%" after scrolling past the hero:

```
.home .ha-header {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

I think she was confused as to what I was referencing, since my issue doesn't pertain to the home page. So, I took what code she had and tried to apply it to the submenu on hover, since it is only displayed in that state.

It seems like I should be able to fix this with CSS, but I'm clearly missing something, because what I'm doing is not working to get the submenu to display over the hero unit:

```
.ha-header ul.sub-menu:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0%) !important;
  transform: translateY(0%) !important;
}
```

I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree. Would someone mind taking a look and seeing where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to look at this closer and found my solution. One of the solutions I originally tried involved setting the z-index value of the submenu. However, it wasn't working for me, so I thought what the developer sent me was what was causing the issue (hence the above question.) After not finding a solution with that, I revisted z-index.

I forgot one of the rules of using z-index for navigation is to make sure that the parent element doesn't have overflow set to hidden. In my case, it wasn't the immediate parent element, but one further up the chain causing the visibility issue.

So I was able to add the following to my CSS:

```
.ha-header-hide {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

to correct the issue and allow the submenu to display on hover over the hero unit.

Hope this reminder helps someone else.